# Activity annotation for Android

Tags: android, android-activity

There isn't something like MonoDroid [[Acitvity()]](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.cs) attribute/annotation for Android Java SDK? While it is not strange thing in Java (for example [WebServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation) it is not possible to have something like that in Android Java SDK?

In fact, I am tired of editing AndroidManifest.xml!

Comment: You may have better luck getting answers if you would take the time to explain what "MonoDroid attribute for activities" means.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare. Sorry if my question is not clear, please look at this sample code https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your activities must, in fact, be declared in the manifest.  I haven't seen any way to get around this so far.  Of course, you could imagine some sort of tool that did post processing on your application (via Eclipse or something like that) and generated your manifest for you.  However, I haven't seen such a thing, and doubt such a thing exists.  Instead, people typically just declare them in the manifest (it takes a few seconds at most), or create them in Eclipse and let it do the "dirty work."

Comment: One thing, though, the manifest says things your app sometimes *can't*.  For example, you can include extraneous activities you don't actually want used, for example, if they are left in because of a library containing dead code, and you don't want them being displayed...

Comment: Sure that's possible, and for activities, why not synthesize the manifest, but there are other pieces of the manifest that can't be synthesized, for example, it's impossible to statically determine the set of permissions the app will use

Comment: What are you talking about?  Java has had annotations at the bytecode level for a long time, and this has nothing to do with determining permission usage.  Determining permission usage would be impossible to do statically for the same reason as any other static analysis, there are lots of places where you have to make approximations, so it's just not possible in the real sense, only an approximation.